# Sorting array of objects based on String property

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have data structure something like this.

```
[
        {"name": "John", "gender": "Male", "id": "1"},
        {"name": "Max", "gender": "Male", "id": "2"},
        {"name": "John", "gender": "Male", "id": "3"},
        {"name": "Sam", "gender": "Male", "id": "4"},
        {"name": "Max", "gender": "Male", "id": "5"},
        {"name": "Sam", "gender": "Male", "id": "6"},
        {"name": "Sam", "gender": "Male", "id": "7"},
        {"name": " ", "gender": "Male", "id": "8"},
        {"name": "John", "gender": "Male", "id": "9"},
        {"name": " ", "gender": "Male", "id": "10"},
    ]
```

I am trying to sort on it based on `name` property.
I need all the records with `name=max` should come first followed by `name=Sam` and then `name=John` and the remaining records that have empty name field or any other value.

I tried different techniques but didn't get the desired results.

Can someone suggest to me how I can achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: you can use Array.prototype.sort() with a custom compare function. take a look https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give scores to each `name` case, and then use the score in `Array.sort` function.

```js
const data = [
  { name: 'John', gender: 'Male', id: '1' },
  { name: 'Max', gender: 'Male', id: '2' },
  { name: 'John', gender: 'Male', id: '3' },
  { name: 'Sam', gender: 'Male', id: '4' },
  { name: 'Max', gender: 'Male', id: '5' },
  { name: 'Sam', gender: 'Male', id: '6' },
  { name: 'Sam', gender: 'Male', id: '7' },
  { name: ' ', gender: 'Male', id: '8' },
  { name: 'John', gender: 'Male', id: '9' },
  { name: ' ', gender: 'Male', id: '10' }
];

const getScore = name => {
  if (name === 'Max') return 3;
  else if (name === 'Sam') return 2;
  else if (name === 'John') return 1;
  else return 0;
};

data.sort((a, b) => getScore(b.name) - getScore(a.name));

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following,

```js
data = [
        {"name": "John", "gender": "Male", "id": "1"},
        {"name": "Max", "gender": "Male", "id": "2"},
        {"name": "John", "gender": "Male", "id": "3"},
        {"name": "Sam", "gender": "Male", "id": "4"},
        {"name": "Max", "gender": "Male", "id": "5"},
        {"name": "Sam", "gender": "Male", "id": "6"},
        {"name": "Sam", "gender": "Male", "id": "7"},
        {"name": " ", "gender": "Male", "id": "8"},
        {"name": "John", "gender": "Male", "id": "9"},
        {"name": " ", "gender": "Male", "id": "10"},
    ]

data.sort((a, b) => {
  if(a.name < b.name) {
    return 1;
  } else if(a.name > b.name) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
})

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thanks, sabbir.alam for the answer.
I even tried this solution but output that I am expecting is. Max, Sam, John. etc.
Above code gives Sam, Max, John, etc.

Answer (score 0):

What if your data contains case sensitive name ?

```
const getScore = name => {
  if (name.toLowerCase() === 'max') return 3;
  else if (name.toLowerCase() === 'sam') return 2;
  else if (name.toLowerCase() === 'john') return 1;
  else return 0;
};
data.sort((a, b) => getScore(b.name) - getScore(a.name));
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi you can use this code

```
var arr = [
    {"name": "John", "gender": "Male", "id": "1"},
    {"name": "Max", "gender": "Male", "id": "2"},
    {"name": "John", "gender": "Male", "id": "3"},
    {"name": "Sam", "gender": "Male", "id": "4"},
    {"name": "Max", "gender": "Male", "id": "5"},
    {"name": "Sam", "gender": "Male", "id": "6"},
    {"name": "Sam", "gender": "Male", "id": "7"},
    {"name": " ", "gender": "Male", "id": "8"},
    {"name": "John", "gender": "Male", "id": "9"},
    {"name": " ", "gender": "Male", "id": "10"},
];

var arr1 = arr.filter((value, index) => {

    if(value.name == 'Max'){
        return value
    }

});

var arr2 = arr.filter((value, index) => {

    if(value.name != 'Max'){
        return value
    }

});

arr2 = arr2.sort((a, b) => (a.name < b.name) ? 1 : -1);

var output = arr1.concat(arr2);

console.log(output);
```